# java, swing - Adding a JlayeredPane in JScrollPane only shows a blank background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlayeredpane

I have already searched for a solution for this but they did not work. Maybe because mine is set-up differently. I'm trying to make an elevator simulator and i have this diagram: 
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sevCb.png)
and i have this code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        JButton floor = new JButton();
        JLabel cab = new JLabel();
        JPanel floorPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel cabPanel = new JPanel();
        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();

        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        constraints.insets = new Insets(20, 92, 20, 92);

        floorPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
        floorPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(165, 165));

        floor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(165, 165));
        floor.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        floor.setText("1");

        cab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(165, 165));
        cab.setText("Cab");
        cab.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        cab.setLocation(0, 0);

        cabPanel.setLayout(null);
        cabPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(165, 165));
        cabPanel.setOpaque(false);
        cabPanel.add(cab);

        layeredPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(165, 165));
        layeredPane.add(floorPanel, 0);
        layeredPane.add(cabPanel, 1);

        scroll.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(183, 660));
        scroll.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(183, 660));
        scroll.setViewportView(layeredPane);

        contentPane.add(scroll, constraints);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

It wont display the two JPanels added to the JLayeredPane and only displays a blank background. I tried the setOpaque(false) on the JPanel in the second layer of the JLayeredPane but it still didn't work.

If by chance you have already found a solution somewhere please send a link.
Ps. sorry for the wrong grammars

Comment: Please create and post in your question a complete yet simple small example program that shows us the problem, one that compiles and runs for us, a [mcve].

Comment: Question: Why are you embedding the JLayeredPane in a JPanel? This does not appear to serve any purpose.

Comment: Okay thanks. Im new here so i didn't know about that, im going to edit it. And about embedding it to the JPanel, its because JPanel has a layout and JLayaredPane don't have one as a default and adding one removes the layering feature that it has or so what I found as a solution. But still didn't work.

Comment: But if all you're doing is adding the JLayeredPane to the JPanel and adding nothing else to the JPanel, it serves no purpose and can add confusion or problems.

Comment: The main problem is that adding the JlayeredPane to a JScroll wont display the JLayeredPane so I tried adding it to a JPanel then added to the Scroll. But it still did not work.

Comment: Your JLayeredPane should not have a layout (as you already know), and you need to set the size and location (or bounds to get both) of an item added to a JLayeredPane since it behaves like a null layout *with layers*.

Comment: Okay. Its now displaying the child containers but how it layers it doesn't seem to work correctly. But thanks though, that seems to be the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again with a JLayeredPane you will need to set the location and position of any component added to the JLayeredPane since it acts as if it has a null layout, but with layers.

For example, check out and run this code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LayeredExample extends JPanel {

    public LayeredExample() {
        int gridRows = 20;
        int gridCols = 10;
        JPanel panelA = new JPanel(new GridLayout(gridRows, gridCols));
        for (int i = 0; i < gridRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridCols; j++) {
                String labelText = String.format("[%d, %d]", j + 1, i + 1);
                JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText);

                Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE);
                Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3);
                label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder));
                panelA.add(label);
            }
        }
        panelA.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel A"));
        panelA.setSize(panelA.getPreferredSize());
        panelA.setLocation(0, 0);

        JLabel dragMeLabel = new JLabel("Drag Me!");
        dragMeLabel.setFont(dragMeLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 54f));
        JPanel panelB = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panelB.add(dragMeLabel);
        panelB.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel B"));
        panelB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        panelB.setSize(panelB.getPreferredSize());
        panelB.setLocation(200, 200);

        MouseAdapter myMouse = new MouseAdapter() {
            private Point p0;
            private Point loc0;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                p0 = e.getLocationOnScreen();
                loc0 = ((JComponent) e.getSource()).getLocation();
            }

            private void moveComponent(MouseEvent e) {
                if (p0 == null || loc0 == null) {
                    return;
                }
                Point p1 = e.getLocationOnScreen();
                JComponent comp = (JComponent)e.getSource();
                Container cont = comp.getParent();
                int x = loc0.x + p1.x - p0.x;
                int y = loc0.y + p1.y - p0.y;
                Point loc1 = new Point(x, y);
                comp.setLocation(loc1);
                cont.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                moveComponent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                moveComponent(e);
                p0 = null;
                loc0 = null;
            }
        };

        panelB.addMouseListener(myMouse);
        panelB.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);

        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.add(panelA, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        layeredPane.add(panelB, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1600, 1200));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(layeredPane);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 650));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayeredExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new LayeredExample());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Following your example fixed the problem about the JLayeredPane not following the given index. Thanks a lot for your help. :D